# Is there a way to make a browser to confirm when l move away from a web page?

Tags: browser, internet, links

Whenever I browser a site, I scroll and click different objects on the page. Sometimes I click on the wrong object, and page begins to change and load a site I don't want to visit. Then I have to go back, which means the browser has to load the first page again. This happens a lot.

Is there a way to make it so the browser asks for confirmation before changing the page?

As in, when I:

- Type a URL in the address bar and press enter,
- Click a hyperlink or element on a page,
- Trigger some JavaScript event that changes the page after a certain time,

Is there a setting/browser/browser add-on that brings up a window that asks if I want to go to the page?

If I accept, the site should load normally.
If I decline, no change in the current page loaded should occur.
No matter how many times I click, the page should not change unless I confirm the window.

I'm thinking of something that intercepts the GET request the browser sends, but I'm not a internet software developer.

Any suggestions? I'm currently using firefox and palemoon on Windows 7/10.

Note: Sorry for the double [post](https://superuser.com/questions/1656590/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-browser-to-confirm-when-i-move-away-from-a-web-page), not sure why I ended up on a different account with the same email.

Comment: Welcome to SU SE! If you haven't already consider taking a tour to get the most from this site.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is an accidental double-post: https://superuser.com/q/1656590/167207

Comment: I actually can't login to the other account. Not sure how two accounts got made, I signed in with the same email.

Comment: In order to merge accounts please use the [contact](https://superuser.com/contact) form and select "I need to merge accounts". Please see https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts

Answer (score 0):

This plugin will - https://github.com/codedance/jquery.AreYouSure

It leverages 'onBeforeUnload' to detect all page/browser exit events.

You may have to tweak the code to work exactly as intended but this is close.

Comment: So I would use something to inject the JS code into the page? Ok thanks, will try it out. Is there another way that does not involve JS?

Comment: Could be but I'm not aware of it. Why don't you want to involve JS, are you running high security settings?

Comment: Nah, just want stuff to load faster. I usually disable it or block scripts that take up too much memory and hang.